# AngularJS filter не возвращает 0

Tags: angularjs, select, filter

Есть некий селект:

```
<select ng-model="compareFull[$parent.$index][$index].first"  ng-options="first.value as first.index for first in indexes | filter: filterList('value')"></select>
```

здесь важен

```
filter: filterList('value')
```

где наш список припустим

```
$scope.indexes = [
        {index:'$result', value:0},
        {index:'$result_etalon', value:1},
        {index:'$result_for_etalon', value:2},
        {index:'$hello', value:3},
        {index:'$hello_etalon', value:4},
        {index:'$hello_for_etalon', value:5},
    ];
```

Хочу вывести только те элементы которые удовлетворяют условие по функции, не выводить те элементы остаток деления которых на 3 == 2

```
 $scope.filterList = function(prop){
        return function(item){
            if(item[prop]%3!=2){
                return item[prop];
            }
        }
    }
```

Но первый элемент не выводит, в данном случае не выводит в списку `item[prop]=0`, хотя условие удовлетворяет

Comment: приведите пример на Plunkr или тут в snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заблуждение было относительно того что должна возвращать функция.

Так как это фильтр, то и работает эта функция как фильтр, а именно: если элемент удовлетворяет условия - возвращает `true` если не удовлетворяет `false`

Так как в данном случае возвращается сам элемент, конкретно `0` то он, приводится к `false` и фильтр решает что элемент выводить не нужно.

Следовательно код нужно изменить, например, на

```
$scope.filterList = function(prop){
    return function(item){
        return (item[prop]%3!=2);
    }
}
```