# Angular JS , прятать определенные ланные

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте , не могли бы подсказать каким параметром можно задать запрет вывода 0 числа.
Есть таблица в которые выводятся рейтинги , и в данный момент много строк где выводится число 0. Как можно запретить отображение таких строк?

```
   <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | orderBy: '-B_4011' ">
<td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{ $index + 1}}</td>
<td><img src="{{cup.Addon_1}}" width="30" height="30"></td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.user}}</td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.B_4011 / 10000 | number:0 }}</td>
```

Comment: Сами балы выводятся в строке  <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.B_4011 / 10000 | number:0 }}</td>

Comment: что значит _задать запрет вывода 0 числа_? ты хочешь не показывать всю строку (tr)? тогда просто используй `$filter` по нужному полю, вернее в разметке он будет `filter`

Comment: Да , мне надо прятать строку , а как правильно указать фильтр? {{cup.B_4011 / 10000 | filter: >0 }} таким образом?

Comment: нет что-то вроде `cups | filter:comparator | orderBy` где comparator - Это функция которая будет проверять значение

Comment: А как должна выглядеть сама функция запрещающая вывод строк с 0 ? Я сижу ищу , нашел только 1 похожую тему , но разобраться не могу=(  [http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490254/angularjs-filter-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-0/490265]

Comment: функция должна возвращать false если не надо выводить элемент и true если надо. Первый параметр у нее - проверяемый элемент.

Comment: Могу я Вас попросить написать эту функцию(для дальнейшего разбора) , так как не представляю как ее сделать

Comment: Подскажите что я должен исправить тут?`CupApp.filter('delNull', function(){
    return function(item){
        if(item.indexOf("0")!==-1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return item;
        }
    }
})`

Comment: не туда ты немного пошел. `item` - это твой `cup` из разметки, если тебе надо чтобы `cup.B_4011 / 10000` не равнялся 0 так и проверяй это

Comment: Ну по тому что я написал - у меня 0 заменяет на фразу false

Comment: сделай пример где-нибудь на [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) как это сейчас работает.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/XThL9NRSCS2IT2YdTCcu?p=preview   вот пример

Comment: что-то я запутался. Тебе же надо всю строчку убрать? почему ты тогда фильтр применяешь к ячейке, а не к коллекции, как я выше показал: `cups | filter:comparator`?

Comment: Да , всю строку. Я просто не понимаю как нужно применять этот фильт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы убрать ненужные строки нужно отфильтровать коллекцию *cups*.

Это можно сделать либо в коде javascript? используя [метод filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), Либо примерить фильтр [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) непосредственно в разметке, передав ему функцию, которая скажет нужно ли убрать элемент или нет.

Данная функция может выглядеть так

```
function comparator(cup){
    return number(cup.B_4011 / 10000, 0) != 0;
}
```

где `number` - это [соответствующий фильтр](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number)

Для использования во view, данную функцию нужно поместить в scope, например так:

```
$scope.comparator = comparator;
```

И использовать непосредственно во view

```
<tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | filter:comparator | orderBy: '-B_4011' ">
```

Пример:

```js
var CupApp = angular.module('CupApp', []);
CupApp.controller('CupCtrl', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var number = $filter('number');

  function comparator(cup) {
    return number(cup.B_4011 / 10000, 0) != 0;
  }
  $scope.comparator = comparator;
  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/vubb3').success(function(data) {
    $scope.cups = data.concat({
      B_4011: 20000
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="CupApp" ng-controller="CupCtrl">
  <h2>Суммы заказов</h2>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Место</th>
      <th>Фото</th>
      <th>Закупщик</th>
      <th>Балы</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | filter:comparator | orderBy: '-B_4011' ">
      <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{ $index + 1}}</td>
      <td><img src="{{cup.Addon_1}}" width="30" height="30"></td>
      <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.user}}</td>
      <td ng-style="$index < 3 ? {'font-size' : '16pt'}: ''">{{cup.B_4011 / 10000 | number:0}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!